# finish() inside onCreate() invalid callbacks

Tags: android

as per onCreate documentation:

> You can call `finish()` from within this function, in which case
>   `onDestroy()` will be immediately called without any of the rest of the
>   activity lifecycle (`onStart(), onResume(), onPause()`, etc) executing.

But I'm facing a different behaviour. `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called after the `onCreate` and only after that `onDestroy`. Any suggestions?

The code I'm running:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (...) {
            startActivity(...);
            finish();
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `finish()`? Are you using (implicit) `this` pointer to the activity instance or are you trying to invoke finish() on an activity that's currently not in front of the current task?

Comment: I found this quote only here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html
Did you mentioned `PreferenceActivity`? Did you try your code with `PreferenceActivity` or with a normal `Activity`?

Comment: Hm... it's still not enough info. Since your `finish()` call is inside the `onCreate()` method it's possible that your `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` are independent of your `finish()` invocation, but are simply executed before `finish()`, which is most likely the case

Answer (score 3):

Method `onCreateOptionsMenu()` doesn't officially belong to lifecycle methods. Maybe that's why it gets called. If this is a problem for you, you can simply add a check and exit it immediately.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

The code inside your `onCreate()` is absolutely valid.

Comment: Thats what i eventually did, but i wanted to be sure its a normal behaviour. thanks.

Comment: Ditto for `onNewIntent` it seems.